# ansible diff ignore order of lines

Tags: ansible, diff

The diff command entered directly form Ubuntu provides the the expected output, But when its entered via playbook it gives the following errors:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ diff <(sort CSR1_route.txt) <(sort CSR2_route.txt) >> delta1.txt ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ more delta1.txt 13c13 < O        2.2.2.2 [110/2] via 192.168.255.134, 01:36:31, GigabitEthernet1
---
> O        1.2.2.2 [110/2] via 192.168.255.134, 01:36:31, GigabitEthernet1


- name: testing_diff   shell: diff <(sort CSR1_route.txt) <(sort CSR2_route.txt) >> delta4.txt

fatal: [CSR1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "diff <(sort CSR1_route.txt) <(sort CSR2_route.txt) >> delta4.txt",
    "delta": "0:00:00.001697",
    "end": "2018-12-05 16:34:59.665114",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "diff <(sort CSR1_route.txt) <(sort CSR2_route.txt) >> delta4.txt",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 2,
    "start": "2018-12-05 16:34:59.663417",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
```

Comment: Thanks Graham for editing, I need to figure out how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 -

```
- name: testing_diff   
  shell: |
    diff file1 file2 >> delta4.txt
```

Solution 2 -

```
- name: testing_diff   
  shell: |
    diff file1 file2 >> delta4.txt
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Solution 3 -
If not try the command module.

Comment: Option 2 giving errors but works:
fatal: [CSR1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "diff <(sort CSR1_route.txt) <(sort CSR2_route.txt) >> delta4.txt;",
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "diff <(sort CSR1_route.txt) <(sort CSR2_route.txt) >> delta4.txt;",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": "/bin/bash",
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []

Comment: Did you try the third option as well?

Comment: Command module results in "stderr": "diff: extra operand '<(sort'\ndiff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.",

Comment: "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "diff <(sort CSR1_route.txt) <(sort CSR2_route.txt) >> delta4.txt",

Comment: Tried to edit the format, the help page did not really help. Maybe I look at the wrong doc.

Comment: For now I'll just go with option 2 with ignore_errors: true
- name: testing_diff
      shell: diff <(sort CSR1_route.txt) <(sort CSR2_route.txt) >> delta4.txt;
      args:
          executable: /bin/bash
      ignore_errors: true